# Using Excel, how can I automate incoming weekly reports/audits to pull data and insert into a new report?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, automation, vlookup, report

I'm trying to figure out where to start with this so I appreciate any suggestions on something I can do some further research on.

My work relies heavily on reports & audits weekly (sometimes daily) and I'm trying to figure a solution to automate the data I need into a report I normally do manually. There is a lot of unnecessary data within these reports and I pull things I need using vlookups, but it takes quite a bit of time for something I'm sure is a quicker method. The data is exported as an excel worksheet/csv.

Can it be automated in Excel?
Could it be automated from the incoming email?

Appreciate any help,
thanks

Comment: Entirely (Heavily) depends on the format and content.

Comment: If the data is highly structured, then formulas may work. To go from the email will require VBA.